# Fetching html content with python 3

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to get 10 day weather forecast, unable to  the exact html from website. I'm stuck at this point

```
import mechanicalsoup
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image
import imghdr
import urllib.request
import io
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("http://www.intellicast.com/")
browser.select_form()
browser["query"] = input("enter city,country")
response = browser.submit_selected()
html = response.text
html = html.replace('<!--[if lte IE 9]>', '').replace('<![endif]-->', '')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
trial = soup.find("div", {"class": "main container clearfix"})
print(trial)`
```

please help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does not work? What have you tried to resolve this?

Comment: for 10 day weather forecast it generated by javascript you need selenium or use [free weather API](https://openweathermap.org/api)

Comment: I'm new to python, attempted above code to fetch 10 day forecast. I was stuck at that point and couldn't able to print required html. Thanks @bunglehead

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it not possible with python @ewwink

Comment: you can use selenium in python, `pip install selenium` and use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=webdriverwait+python) to wait "10 day" element located

Comment: Thanks for your help @ewwink.